# How to access parent's controller function from within a custom directive using *parent's* ControllerAs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm in need of building a transformation directive that transforms custom directives into html.

- Input like: `<link text="hello world"></link>`
- should output to: `<a class="someclass" ng-click="linkClicked('hello world')"></a>`

*linkClicked* should be called on the parent controller of the directive.

It would have been very easy if I was the one responsible for the html holding the 'link' directive (using isolated scope), but I'm not. It's an **as-is** input and I have to figure a way to still do it.

There are countless examples on how to do similar bindings using the default scope of the directive, but I'm writing my controllers using [John Papa's](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y075) recommendations with controllerAs, but don't want to create another instance on the controller in the directive.

This is what I have reached so far:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('link', link);

    link.$inject = ['$compile'];

    function link($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: '<a class="someclass"></a>',
            terminal: true,
            priority: 1000,
            link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                element.removeAttr('link'); // Remove the attribute to avoid indefinite loop.

                element.attr('ng-click', 'linkClicked(\'' + attributes.text + '\')');

                $compile(element)(scope);
        },
    };
}
})();
```

- `$scope.linkClicked = function(text){...}` in the parent controller *works*.
- `element.attr('ng-click', 'abc.linkClicked(..)')` in the directive (where the parent's controllerAs is abc) - *also works*.

**The problem** is I don't know which controller will use my directive and can't hard-code the 'abc' name in it.

What do you suggest I should be doing?

Comment: pass in what you need as attributes to directive scope,...then it doesn't matter what the parent is

Comment: You shouldn't be making assumptions about controllers in your directive - true. But also, you shouldn't be making assumptions about there being a `linkClicked()` in the scope of the View where the directive is used.

Comment: Apparently, there's no winning with this issue .. Thanks for commenting you guys.

Comment: @wilenx., I'm still not clear exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Just follow the normal directive approach of an isolate scope and passing the parameters you need to a directive. Also, what should be the content of `<a>`?

Comment: @NewDev, (1) I'm receiving a string of html that includes, among others, this link directive. It only has that text attribute. If I could, I would have rewritten that link directive in a way that would call the function needed in a normal way (like you suggest), but I have to generate and render those calls by myself. Having said that, I need to call the parent's function of my choosing, passing in the text for processing. It's a crappy situation, I get that, but I still need to patch this thing ... (2) The content of <a> is irrelevant to the matter at hand.

Comment: @wilenx., "I need to call the parent's function of my choosing" - where is that "choosing" happening (or ought to happen)?

Comment: @NewDev, the original directive creator doesn't know (or care) what happens with it. My directive chooses which html to generate, so when adding the 'ng-click' attribute, I need to reference *a* function to handle the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to understand from your question all the constraints that you are facing, but if the only HTML you get is:

```
<link text="some text">
```

and you need to generate a call to *some* function, then the function must either be:

1. *assumed* by the directive, or
2. *conveyed* to the directive

**#1** is problematic because the user of the directive now needs to understand its internals. Still, it's possible if you assume that a function name is `linkClicked` (or whatever you want to call it), and the user of your directive would have to take special care to alias the function he really needs (could be done with "controllerAs" as well):

```
<div ng-controller="FooCtrl as foo" ng-init="linkClicked = foo.actualFunctionOfFoo">
   ...

   <link text="some text">

   ...
</div>
```

```
app.directive("link", function($compile){
  return {
    transclude: "element", // remove the entire element
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
      var template = '<a class="someclass" ng-click="linkClicked(\'' + 
                      attrs.text +
                     '\')">link</a>';

      $compile(template)(scope, function(clone){
        element.after(clone);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5nS4HOQ6Ug5t8mdgR0vG?p=preview)**

**#2** is typically achieved via attributes, which isn't possible in your case. But you could also create a sort of "proxy" directive - let's call it `onLinkClick` - that could execute whatever expression you need:

```
<div ng-controller="FooCtrl as foo"
     on-link-click="foo.actualFunctionOfFoo($data)">
   ...

   <link text="some text">

   ...
</div>
```

The `link` directive now needs to `require: "onLinkClick"`:

```
app.directive("link", function($compile){
  return {
    transclude: "element", // remove the entire element
    scope: true,
    require: "?^onLinkClick",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
      if (!ctrl) return;
      var template = '<a class="someclass" ng-click="localClick()">link</a>';

      scope.localClick = function(){
        ctrl.externalFn(attrs.text);
      };

      $compile(template)(scope, function(clone){
        element.after(clone);
      });
    }
  };
});

app.directive("onLinkClick", function($parse){
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    controller: function($scope, $attrs){
      var ctrl = this;
      var expr = $parse($attrs.onLinkClick);

      ctrl.externalFn = function(data){
        expr($scope, {$data: data});
      };
    },
  };
});
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/CD1Q1WJfpZNNS85k1p1A?p=preview)**

Notice that having a `link` directive would also execute on `<link>` inside `<head>`. So, make attempts to detect it and skip everything. For the demo purposes, I used a directive called `blink` to avoid this issue.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot!